# Azure Logic App giving Bad Gateway error when connecting with SFTP server

Tags: sftp, azure-logic-apps, bad-gateway, ssh2-sftp

I am trying to create Logic App using SFTP connector that triggers when a file is uploaded to server. While establishing a connection with SFTP server using Password authentication I am getting the error "***BadGateway More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is***".Any ideas why I may be getting this error ? Please tell me the correct fields to enter the values. I have the following details account = ac240522; password = ****; server = mft.company.com; protocol = sftp/1234; path = /folder/download.
With the same credentials I was able to connect from File Zilla
[New SFTP Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN4H6.png)

Comment: Please structure the code in a more user friendly format. When everything is one big chunk of text it's harder for human to process.

Answer (score 0):

- As per the Microsoft [troubleshot document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh#sftp---ssh-trigger-when-a-file-is-added-or-modified)

1. Try changing the retry policy of SFTP connection and check the action count of retries
2. check the connectivity issues, run a network trace on your firewall and SFTP server.
3. Check the connection problem is from Logic app end or SFTP end.
4. usually band gateway issues are associated with [whitelisting of managed connectors IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#multi-tenant-azure---outbound-ip-addresses)